# JQuery add click event to unknown div id

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, html

I'm loading a php page that shows multiple elements, depending of the users (so i can't know how many items will be show). Those elements looks like :

```
<div id='container_feed'>
    <div id='feed_element' data-userid='4'>Random Dude</div>
    <div id='feed_element' data-userid='5'>Random Dude 2</div>
</div>
```

I'd like to add a click() event on each div and load a page depending of their userid HTML5 tag with .load()

I tried child(), each(), and some other method whithout success...

How can i add this event ?

Thanks.

Comment: First of all change `id='feed_element'` to `class='feed_element'`. An id has to be unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just delegate all the clicks like so:

```
/* You could also use '>div' if you can't guarantee the class name */
$('#container_feed').on('click', '.feed-element' , function() {});
```

That way, you're only adding the one event initially, but all divs inside will be handled by the click event. No need to loop through each element, using `.children` or `.each` or even `$('#container_feed .feed-element')`.

Delegation is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

First, don't use multiple IDs of same name. Use a CSS-`class`.
Then access the userid in your click function like that:

**Code Example:**

```
$("div.feed_element").click(function(e) {
    var clickedUserId = $(this).data('userid');

    $('.userdata-container').load('ajax/userpage_' + clickedUserId +'.html');
});
```

**Corresponding HTML:**

```
<div id='container_feed'>
    <div class='feed_element' data-userid='4'>Random Dude</div>
    <div class='feed_element' data-userid='5'>Random Dude 2</div>
</div>
<div class='userdata-container'>
    <!-- The Ajax Code is loaded into this container -->
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds like what i'd like to do, bu it don't work... I put the jquery code just after my      $('#container_feed').load('messages_feed.php');
is it a problem ?

Comment: Ok, my problem seems to be here, if i put the HTML directly in my file (without the .load) it works just fine, but with the .load method, it's not working. Any idea about this ?

Answer (score 1):

you can't have the same id for different elements, that's the point for an id (it should be unique). Use a class instead or just all div children from the main div

```
$('#container_feed div').on('click',function(){
  // do something, the the userid data, load the page somewhere, etc...
})
```

or use a class

html:

```
<div id='container_feed'>
  <div class='feed_element' data-userid='4'>Random Dude</div>
  <div class='feed_element' data-userid='5'>Random Dude 2</div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$('.feed_element').on('click',function(){
  // do something, the the userid data, load the page somewhere, etc...
})
```

newer versions of jquery recomends "on('click',function(){})" instead of "click(function(){})", i guess "click" will be deprecated sometime in the future and "on" can also replace "live()"

Comment: Just to be clear, `on` already replaced `live`. `live` was deprecated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..

```
$("div[id='feed_element']").click(function() {
     // Your stuff
});
```

You should use class, As ID is always used for unique identification.

Comment: Where you have write this code? It must execute after your document gets load.

Comment: In my <script> scope, just after the page loading with .load

Answer (score 0):

First i would not use the same feed_element id for all divs.

Try this

```
$('#container_feed').children().each(function(){
  if($(this).attr('data-userid') == # you want){
    $(this).click(function(){
      //your stuff here
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".feed_element").click(function(event) {
    var userId = $(this).attr('data-userid');
    //make your ajax call.
});
```